# Is there a good way to allow the clients of a server to access other clients directly without using a Mutex?

Tags: rust, tcp

I am working on a crate in which there are `Server` and `Client` structs that are wrappers for the sending and receiving of data. I am trying to find a way for the server to store a list of the connected clients and for the client handler closures to have access to said list but from separate threads. I want to try not to use a `Mutex` as that can be a bottleneck to performance.

I have tried using crossbeam's `SegQueue` but it only has `push()` and `pop()` and I need to be able to access and remove all clients like you could with a vector.

Here is the server code:

```rust
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder;

pub enum ReadEvent {
    Disconnected,
    ReceivedError(String),
    InvalidPacket,
}

pub enum SendEvent {
    NotConnected,
}

pub enum ConnectionError {
    FailedToConnect(String),
}

pub struct Client {
    address: Option<String>,
    stream: Option<TcpStream>,
    pub(crate) disconnected: bool,
}

impl Client {

    /// Will connect to an IP and Port and return a new client object
    /// Clients only work with Notitia servers so this method can not be accessed by users
    pub(crate) fn new<S: Into<String>>(ip: S, port: S) -> Self {
        let address = format!("{}:{}", ip.into(), port.into());

        let stream_result = TcpStream::connect(address.clone());
        if stream_result.is_err() {
            panic!("Client failed to connect to address {}", address);
        }

        Self {
            address: Some(address),
            stream: Some(stream_result.unwrap()),
            disconnected: false
        }
    }

    /// Creates a client from an existing connection
    /// /// Clients only work with Notitia servers so this method can not be accessed by users
    pub(crate) fn from<S: Into<String>>(address: S, stream: TcpStream) -> Self {
        Self {
            address: Some(address.into()),
            stream: Some(stream),
            disconnected: false
        }
    }

    pub(crate) fn connect<S: Into<String>>(&mut self, ip: S, port: S) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        self.disconnect();
        self.disconnected = false;
        let address = format!("{}:{}", ip.into(), port.into());
        self.address = Some(address.clone());
        let stream = TcpStream::connect(address);
        if stream.is_err() {
            return Err(ConnectionError::FailedToConnect(stream.unwrap_err().to_string()));
        }
        self.stream = Some(stream.unwrap());
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn disconnect(&mut self) {
        self.stream = None;
        self.address = None;
        self.disconnected = true;
    }

    fn try_get_stream(&mut self) -> Option<&TcpStream> {
        self.disconnect(); // ensure the Client object is disconnected
        let stream = self.stream.as_ref().unwrap();
        Some(stream)
    }

    /// Sends data to the stream
    pub fn send<S: Into<String>>(&mut self, data: S) -> Result<(), SendEvent> {
        let stream = self.try_get_stream();
        if stream.is_none() {
            return Err(SendEvent::NotConnected);
        }
        // Writes to the stream here
        Ok(())
    }

    /// Sends an error to the client and if it should disconnect
    pub fn send_error<S: Into<String>>(&mut self, error: S, disconnect: bool) -> Result<(), SendEvent> {
        let stream = self.try_get_stream();
        if stream.is_none() {
            return Err(SendEvent::NotConnected);
        }
        // writes an error to the stream
        Ok(())
    }

    /// Waits until a message is received from the stream
    pub fn read(&mut self) -> Result<String, ReadEvent> {
        let stream = self.try_get_stream();
        if stream.is_none() {
            return Err(ReadEvent::Disconnected);
        }
        // Reads data from the stream and processes it into a string output
        Ok(format!(""))
    }
}

impl Clone for Client {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        let address_clone = if self.address.is_none() {
            None
        } else {
            let addr = self.address.as_ref().unwrap();
            Some(addr.clone())
        };

        let stream = if self.stream.is_none() {
            None
        } else {
            let s = self.stream.as_ref().unwrap();
            let c = s.try_clone();
            if c.is_err() {
                None
            } else {
                Some(c.unwrap())
            }
        };

        Self {
            address: address_clone,
            stream,
            disconnected: self.disconnected
        }
    }
}

pub enum ServerError {
    FailedToBindAddr(String),
}

pub struct Server {
    address: String,
    connected: Vec<Client> // <--- The vector in question
}

impl Server {

    pub fn new<IP: Into<String>, PORT: Into<String>>(ip: IP, port: PORT) -> Self {
        Self {
            address: format!("{}:{}", ip.into(), port.into()),
            connected: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
 
    /// Starts the server
    /// max_connections: If Some, will limit the amount of connections to the server at a time
    /// client_handle: A closure that takes a reference to a client and a reference to the vector of clients that are connected
    pub fn start<'a, F: 'a + Fn(&Client, &Vec<Client>) + Send + Sync>(& mut self, max_connections: Option<usize>, client_handle: F) -> Result<(), ServerError> {
        // bind the listener
        let listener_res = TcpListener::bind(self.address.clone());
        if listener_res.is_err() {
            return Err(ServerError::FailedToBindAddr(listener_res.unwrap_err().to_string()));
        }
        let listener = listener_res.unwrap();

        for mut s in listener.incoming() {
            if s.is_err() {
                continue;
            }
            let stream = s.unwrap();

            let sockaddr = stream.peer_addr();
            if sockaddr.is_err() {
                // Write an error to the client
                continue;
            }
            let ip = sockaddr.unwrap().ip().to_string();

            let mut client = Client::from(ip, stream);

            let connections = self.connected.len();

            if max_connections.is_some() && connections >= max_connections.unwrap() {
                client.send_error("Server is full!", true);
                continue;
            }

            self.connected.push(client.clone());

            pool.install(|| { // Uses rayon for the threadpool
                client_handle(&client, &self.connected); // The issue
                client.disconnect();
                // TODO Remove client from self.connected
            });
        }

        Ok(())
    }

}

fn main() {
    thread::spawn(move || { // start the client after 5 seconds to give the server time to start up
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(5000));
        let mut client = Client::new("localhost", "2277");
    });
    let mut server = Server::new("0.0.0.0", "2277");
    server.start(Some(20), |client, connected| {
        println!("Connected!")
    });
}
```

I am considering making `connected` a hashmap to store a connection ID as well. Is there a good way to allow the clients to access the other connected clients directly without using a `Mutex`? And if not, are there any less-direct ways?

Edit: Updated code to be able to run as requested. (requires the rayon crate to run)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Notably, [items like `network`, `crate::client`, `write_event_error` are missing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17c7837f203ddbcb8fb589384a106e05). Please follow the above tips to remove or reduce these missing pieces.

Comment: Okay! I will try to get one going in the rust playground!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, I have found a solution in rust's RWLock, which individually locks reading and writing of data, making it more efficient than a mutex.